# What is the Regular Expression for special characters (everything except digits & alphabets) in java

Tags: java, string

I wish to convert all the special characters(everything except digits & alphabets) to the character '*' by using replaceAll()

```
string2=string1.replaceAll("[RegX]", "*")
```

What shall I write in place of **RegX** ?

Comment: `[^0-9a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: @Sweeper not a very international solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work : `\W`. It [*matches anything other than a letter, digit or underscore.*](https://regex101.com/)

We just need to add the `_` to pick it up also.

```
string2 = string1.replaceAll("[\\W_]", "*")
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5jVnEr/1)**

Answer (score 0):

The regexp `"[^\\p{IsLatin}\\p{Digit}]"` will also recognize language specific characters like `œŒŸÉÑÜÚÓöÄß`.